# Problem with binding Title of WPF window on property in shell view model class [Caliburn.Micro]

Tags: wpf, window, title, caliburn.micro

I have simple problem with binding property in shell view model class on Title property of WPF Window- it’s shell.

My shell view look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Spirit.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Path=Title}" >
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

shell view model class:

```
 [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShellViewModel
    {
        private string _title;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Title);
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Spirit";
        }
    }
```

If I run app Title of shell view (WPF window) is  Namespace.ShellViewModelClass, no value of property Title in shell view model class.

If I active some screen in shell view, Title property of window is  Namespace.ViewModelClass.

How can I remove this behavior? Thank for advice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since IScreen is defined with IHaveDisplayName and the CM framework's Screen class has a property of DisplayName, you just need to set that property in your ShellViewModel, like this:

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
    base.DisplayName = "Spirit";
}
```

Comment: This gives me a R# warning of 'Virtual member call in constructor'. Don't have a good way around it yet though. Can't seal the class either.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell from the code you've given, but I assume that you assign the DataContext of your Window to an instance of ShellViewModel in your code-behind.  When is the ShellViewModel initialized?

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your ViewModel for any properties that you want to see a changed value for.  The link here is to the MSDN documentation, but if you search Google and/or SO for it, you will see plenty of examples.

Comment: I must not implement INotifypropertyChanged interface because I use Caliburn.Micro Framework and my Shell model class is derived from Screen class and this implement this interface.

Comment: Sorry - I based my answer on your original positing, which just had the default get; set; property.  Could you also update your question with the code that initializes the ViewModel and sets it as your DataContext?

Comment: Hi, in caliburn you musn’t init DataContext. For example property of name Wonko in view model is automatically bind on control wih name Wonko in view.

Comment: @jminarik: thanks for the information.  Of all the things I'm unfamiliar with, Caliburn is one of them...  :)